# How to make my buttons shift downwards when my table grows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue with my HTML, where when I go to add more than 3 new assets into my table, the buttons below (Add new asset, save and submit) are not being pushed down. Is this a flex issue and how would I go about solving this? I put all of my buttons into a div because I found this aligned my page better. But when I did not have my buttons in a div, it works. I am reframing my code to have more div's to keep everything contained.

```js
$('document').ready(() => {

    // Handler to Add New Asset
    const table = $("#formTable tbody");
    let count = 1;

    $('#add').click(() => {
        
        const newRow = `
                        
                <tr index="${count}">
                    <form>
                        <td><input id='asset_tag_no${count}' type='text' bottom required /></td>
                        <td><input id='manufacturer_serial_no${count}' type='text' bottom required/></td>
                        <td><input id='description${count}' type='text'/></td>
                        <td><input id='cost${count}' type='value'/></td>
                        <td><input id='po_no${count}' type='text' /></td>
                        <td><input id='rc_to_credit${count}' type='text'/></td>
                        <td><input id='remarks${count}' type='text'/></td>
                        <td><button type="button" index="${count}" class="btn btn-danger btn-remove">X</button></td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
        `;

        table.append(newRow);
        // Handler to Remove New Asset
        $('.btn-remove').click(function(){
            let index = $(this).attr('index');
            $(`tr[index='${index}'`).remove();
        });

        count++;
    });
})
```

```css
.header{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

h1, h2{
    font-size: 1rem;
}


/* table{
    font-size: 10pt;
} */


@media screen {
    input{
        text-align: center;
    } 
    input#date{
        width: -webkit-fill-available;
    }
    .flex {
        display: flex;
        flex: auto;
        height: 100px;
        /* border: 1px solid red; */
      }
      .flex-box {
        width: 40px;
        height: 1000px;
        /* background: pink; */
      }
      .button{
        display: flex;
        /* display: inline !important; */
        flex: auto;
        height: 40px;
        gap: 12px;
      }

      .btn-remove{
        padding: 5px;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        font-size: 0.7rem;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP + JQUERY -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/disposal.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./js/./disposal.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     

    <body>

        <div class="wrapper">
                <form div class="flex">
                    <table>
                        <div class="flex-box"></div>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" id='date'><b>Date:</b></td>
                            <td align="left"><input type="date" id="date" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" id='department'><b>Dept/Division:</b></td>
                            <td align="left"><input type="text" id="department" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" id='location'><b>Location:</b></td>
                            <td align="left"><input type="text" id="location" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" id='resp'><b>Resp. Ctr:</b></td>
                            <td align="left"><input type="text" id="resp" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        
                    </table>
                    </div>
<br><br><br><br>
            <div class="flex">
                    <table class='table' id='formTable'>
                        <div class="flex-box"></div>
                            <tr>
                                <th>&emsp;&emsp;Asset Tag No.</th>
                                <th>Manufacturer Serial No.</th>
                                <th>&emsp;&emsp;&ensp;Description</th>
                                <th>&emsp;&emsp;Cost/ Est. Cost</th>
                                <th>&emsp;&thinsp;Method of Disposal</th>
                                <th>&emsp;&emsp;RC to Credit</th>
                                <th>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Remarks</th>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
            </div>
<br><br><br><br>  
            <div class="button">
                <div class="flex-box"></div>         
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id='add' >+ Add New Asset</button> 
            </div> 
            <br>
            <div class="button">
                <div class="flex-box"></div>      
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id='save'>SAVE</button>
                <button  class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id='submit' >SUBMIT</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="window.print();return false;"/>EXPORT PDF</button>
            </div> 
            </form>

                

                   
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had added heights for both .flex and .flex-box. This was forcing them to stay the size they were.

Also, you didn't need the form tags for each row.

```js
$('document').ready(() => {

  // Handler to Add New Asset
  const table = $("#formTable tbody");
  let count = 1;

  $('#add').click(() => {

    const newRow = `                        
                <tr index="${count}">
                    <td><input id='asset_tag_no${count}' type='text' bottom required /></td>
                    <td><input id='manufacturer_serial_no${count}' type='text' bottom required/></td>
                    <td><input id='description${count}' type='text'/></td>
                    <td><input id='cost${count}' type='value'/></td>
                    <td><input id='po_no${count}' type='text' /></td>
                    <td><input id='rc_to_credit${count}' type='text'/></td>
                    <td><input id='remarks${count}' type='text'/></td>
                    <td><button type="button" index="${count}" class="btn btn-danger btn-remove">X</button></td>
                </tr>
        `;

    table.append(newRow);
    // Handler to Remove New Asset
    $('.btn-remove').click(function() {
      let index = $(this).attr('index');
      $(`tr[index='${index}'`).remove();
    });

    count++;
  });
})
```

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}


/* table{
    font-size: 10pt;
} */

@media screen {
  input {
    text-align: center;
  }
  input#date {
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
  }
  .flex {
    display: flex;
    flex: auto;
  }
  .flex-box {
    width: 40px;
    /* background: pink; */
  }
  .button {
    display: flex;
    /* display: inline !important; */
    flex: auto;
    height: 40px;
    gap: 12px;
  }
  .btn-remove {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<!-- BOOTSTRAP + JQUERY -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/disposal.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./js/./disposal.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <form div class="flex">
      <table>
        <div class="flex-box"></div>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" id='date'><b>Date:</b></td>
          <td align="left"><input type="date" id="date" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" id='department'><b>Dept/Division:</b></td>
          <td align="left"><input type="text" id="department" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" id='location'><b>Location:</b></td>
          <td align="left"><input type="text" id="location" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" id='resp'><b>Resp. Ctr:</b></td>
          <td align="left"><input type="text" id="resp" /></td>
        </tr>

      </table>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <div class="flex">
    <table class='table' id='formTable'>
      <div class="flex-box"></div>
      <tr>
        <th>&emsp;&emsp;Asset Tag No.</th>
        <th>Manufacturer Serial No.</th>
        <th>&emsp;&emsp;&ensp;Description</th>
        <th>&emsp;&emsp;Cost/ Est. Cost</th>
        <th>&emsp;&thinsp;Method of Disposal</th>
        <th>&emsp;&emsp;RC to Credit</th>
        <th>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Remarks</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <div class="button">
    <div class="flex-box"></div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id='add'>+ Add New Asset</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="button">
    <div class="flex-box"></div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id='save'>SAVE</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id='submit'>SUBMIT</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="window.print();return false;" />EXPORT PDF</button>
  </div>
  </form>




  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this fixed the issue, thank you! Just one question about where the duplicate form tags are located?

Comment: No worries. Please look at your `const newRow =` code in your original. You had `<form>` ... `</form>` before. Since you have no submit button, the form tag serves no real purpose here.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done this in the past is to iterate a row count for each `<tr>` tag as the table is created. This helps with sorting, and you can easily specify a sort order.

However, since your table is pre-existing, the only answer I can really see is to simply rebuild the entire table and flow it into the correct element (the `table` element, in your case). No row order required, just put the rows in, in the order you want them.

I hope that helps a little.

Comment: Try not to link to external resources in answers. Instead, you should explain the idea within that resource and then just cite the source as well. This is helpful for future SO users looking for answers on the off chance that the resource you sited is removed.

Comment: Removed that link, did actually forget. Thanks!